# Google Maps API - Can't use Ajax? Even with json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was trying to use the google maps API within some jQuery ajax, however it looks like I can't do this because it's cross-domain, even though I'm using json?

Why is this?  What should I do to resolve this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=405+Lexington+Avenue+Manhattan+NY',
    error: function(request, status) {
        alert('fail');
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning json content doesn't exclude you from cross-domain restrictions. (You might be confusing json and [jsonp](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) here.)

You can use script, as another person noted, but I would recommend switching to javascript api instead. This one is probably designed to be used in server-side code.

Comment: What does the javascript api do that allows it to do the cross-domain call?

Comment: @DutrowLLC I'd guess, the same jsonp thing :)

Comment: @DutrowLLC JS version seems to be described here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

Answer (score 1):

That's right, cross domain ajax calls are not allowed. Instead create a "script" element on the page with the src set to that URL.

You can also use $.getScript() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: I personally use $.getScript() in these cases as it supports a callback.

Comment: My solution wont work. I didn't realize he was trying to retrieve JSON. I assumed he was trying to load the map lib, which would work with $.getScript().