# Read file from URL javascript through webbrowser

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to read/ download a file which can be accessed on the web via internet using javascript?

A simple example would be -
Say I want to download the JSON object result into a file from this URL -  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=30.223980,-97.77485000000001&sensor=false

I want to use a file open and read buffer kind of method. The main reason for the question is that I have to access a URL and download a wav file using javascript. I will be implementing this in android through the webview, so want to keep it in javascript. I am not sure if I can use ajax or jquery.

Any help will be useful.

Thanks, axs

Answer (score 0):

The url you have mentioned returns you a valid `json` if I hadn't mistaken. In that case you can use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to get the cross domain data via ajax. jQuery provides you with an api [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or you can use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with dataType `jsonp`

PS:Make sure the api supports `jsonp`

After a minute search it is sure that google maps json api doesn't support `jsonp` But 
Check out their [javascript APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/services) in that case. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973303/google-maps-api-cant-use-ajax-even-with-json) SO post too

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to keep it simple, so didn't go to look at jQuery and ajax initially, but seems like they are good options. Will look at them. thanks.